# What is the family of this distribution?

Tags: probability, distributions, prior

When trying to find a prior distribution that factorized in a certain way I ended up with

$p(x) \propto x^{-1} e^{-x^{-1} - x^2},\; x \geq 0$

Does anybody knows if this belongs to a particular distribution family? I looked at Wikipedia's [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_probability_distributions) but couldn't identify it

Comment: It belongs to infinitely many families.  But how would identifying one of them be relevant to any meaningful statistical question?

Comment: I wanted to see if it was an instance of, say, a Weibull distribution, to try to give an interpretation to it, and also to see if some of its characteristics, like moments, are already known

Comment: That suggests you might have some specific questions about this particular prior. Rather than asking whether this prior belongs to some family that has been studied, which only indirectly addresses your needs, consider asking the questions you really need answered. One reason for this note of caution is the coefficients of the moment generating function of $p$ are proportional to values of the Meijer G function $G_{0,0}^{3,0}\left(\frac{1}{4}\left|\matrix{\\-\frac{k+1}{2},-\frac{k}{2},0}\right.\right),$ $k=0,1,2,\ldots,$ indicating that any family containing it might not be well characterized.

Comment: See following posts for analysis of some similar distributions: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/163014/conjugate-for-a-special-normal-distribution/345777#345777   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/345876/conjugate-prior-distribution-for-a-specific-normal-curved-exponential-family/345877#345877

Comment: @kjetilbhalvorsen I can tweak the problem so that I have $x$ instead of $x^2$ in the formula above, and that is an Generalised Inverse Gaussian according to the sources you provided. That is what I was looking for.